# How to OUTER JOIN separately grouped tables with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two separate tables which I need to join based on a grouped date column (original values have specific days, I need them by month) and I cannot seem to find a way to do that since I group them on different characteristics. The tables are as follow:

First:

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`Samples`.`created_at`,'%Y-%m') AS `Month of Created At`
        COUNT(DISTINCT `Samples`.`id`) AS `Samples X`
FROM `samples` AS `Samples`
WHERE `Samples`.`group` = 'x'
       AND `Samples`.`created_at` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 3 YEAR) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY `Month of Created At` ASC
```

The output sample:

```
Month of Created At   Samples X
            2020-01          54
            2020-02         224
            2020-03         467
            2020-04         453
            2020-05         354
```

Second:

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(`Samples`.`created_at`,'%Y-%m') AS `Month of Created At`
        COUNT(DISTINCT `Samples`.`id`) AS `Samples Y`
FROM `samples` AS `Samples`
WHERE `Samples`.`section` = 'y'
       AND `Samples`.`created_at` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 3 YEAR) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY `Month of Created At` ASC
```

The output sample:

```
Month of Created At   Samples Y
            2020-02           2
            2020-05           7
```

I need final result to be this:

```
Month of Created At   Samples X   Samples Y
            2020-01          54
            2020-02         224           2
            2020-03         467
            2020-04         453
            2020-05         354           7
```

Comment: I think you can do it by UNION! would you please provide samples DDL and some records in it.